# Elm Syntax Error on For Function Call

Tags: elm

When I compile this code:

```
module Mpower where
import Html exposing (..)
import List exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (id, type', for, value, class)

customerList = ["Select Customer", "Customer 1","Customer 2","Customer 3"]
productList =  ["Select Product", "Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3"]

optionItem optionname =
  option [ ] [ text optionname ]

selectItem labelname selectlabel listname =
    {
    label [ for labelname ] [ text selectlabel ],
    select [ id labelname ] ( List.map optionItem listname )
    }

view =
  form [ id "quote-form" ] 
        [
        h1 [] [ text "Sensational Quote Request Form" ],
        selectItem  "customer-select" "Customer: " customerList,
        div [ class "quote-button" ] [ text "Request Quote!" ]
        ]

main = view
```

I receive the following error:

Detected errors in 1 module.
[36m-- SYNTAX PROBLEM ------------------------------------------------- test-div.elm[0m

I ran into something unexpected when parsing your code!

19│     label [ for labelname ] [ text selectlabel ],
              [31m^[0m
I am looking for one of the following things:

```
"|"
an equals sign '='
whitespace
```

What is causing this error and how do I resolve it?

The corrected selectItem is as follows:

```
selectItem labelname selectlabel listname =
  div [ ]
    [
    label [ for labelname ] [ text selectlabel ],
    select [ id labelname ] ( List.map optionItem listname )
    ]
```

Comment: Revised selectItem has been entered below original question.

Answer (score 1):

The body of `selectItem` shouldn't be in brackets. That isn't valid syntax. Perhaps you could return a div that wraps the label and select elements?